# Program stuck Java MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I want to get MySQL database data in my java application,
So I use this code for that:

```
//  Data retriveing from database HB_Cash
    try{
        connectDB();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("select * from tbl_day_sheet_status_reports");

        while(rs.next()){
            PB_cash.setText(rs.getString("Handing_Balance_(CASH)"));
            String sv = rs.getString("Handing_Balance_(CASH)");
            sv =  PB_cash.getText();
            int billNumber = Integer.valueOf(sv);
            sv = Integer.toString(billNumber);
            PB_cash.setText(sv);
        }
        con.close();

    }catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
    }
```

When I called this code, it works fine, but sometimes it's stuck
like the 2160.81 data is inserted if it has more data after that, every time it shows this data with message box:

[image]

So I use this SQL create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_day_sheet_status_reports` (
  `DaySheet_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Date` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Previous_Balance_(CASH)` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Previous_Balance_(CHQUE)` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Daily_Collection_(CASH)` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Daily_Collection_(CHQUE)` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Daily_Collection_(CHQUE_NUMBER)` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Bank_Diposits_(CASH)` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Bank_Diposits_(CHQUE)` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Handing_Balance_(CASH)` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Handing_Balance_(CHQUE)` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DaySheet_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Sorry, but no clue what you are asking.

Comment: I'm asking how to get back my real data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the (Er Kapil Mehta) code like this and its works perfect
Thanks for your help

```
try{

     connectDB();
     Statement st = con.createStatement();
     rs = st.executeQuery("select * from tbl_day_sheet_status_reports");

    while(rs.next()){
     PB_cash.setText(rs.getDouble("Handing_Balance_(CASH)")+"");
     String sv = rs.getDouble("Handing_Balance_(CASH)")+"";
     sv =  PB_cash.getText();
     double billNumber = Double.valueOf(sv);
     sv = Double.toString((Double) billNumber);
     PB_cash.setText(sv);
     }
     con.close();

     }catch(Exception ex){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   try{

    connectDB();

    Statement st = con.createStatement();

    rs = st.executeQuery("select * from tbl_day_sheet_status_reports");

    while(rs.next()){
         // You Can get this value as a float of Double 
         //Due to Class Cast Exception your  code is not working when value 
        //comes in float 
        PB_cash.setText(rs.getDouble("Handing_Balance_(CASH)")+"");
        String sv = rs.getDouble("Handing_Balance_(CASH)")+"";
        sv =  PB_cash.getText();
        double billNumber = Double.valueOf(sv);
        sv = Integer.toString(billNumber);
        PB_cash.setText(sv);
    }
    con.close();

}catch(Exception ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: It works, Now it doesn't show previous message. But,retrieve the data its missing the decimal values,(Like 2160.81 data shows 2160 only) But I won't  get full data back,How do i

Comment: change this  sv = Integer.toString(billNumber) to  sv = Float.toString(billNumber);